# Tradingview Strategy : can i use SL/TP and Trailing in one code?

Tags: pine-script

I'm currently trying to use 2 exits parameters in one strategy.
The aim was to use trailing to take profits. The SL / TP should be used if the trailing does not trigger, but the SL / TP goals have been achieved. If I code it as here, only the trailing is triggered, but never the SL / TP. It doesn't matter which goals I use with the TP / SL. Do you have any idea why he does not consider the SL / TP?

```
strategy.entry("long", true, when = Buy, comment="EnterLong")
strategy.close("long", when=Sell, comment ="CloseLong")
strategy.exit("long", profit=100, loss=100, comment = "SLTP")
strategy.exit("long_tsl", "long", trail_points = close *trailpoints /syminfo.mintick, trail_offset = close *offset /syminfo.mintick, comment="Trailing")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a condition for switch from SL/TP "mode" to "trailing" mode and modify your `strategy.exit`. The basics of this idea you can find in [this example](https://www.tradingview.com/script/jjhUHcje-Stepped-trailing-strategy-example/).